# Dynamic sendgrid templates being sent as plain text

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

I'm sending email through sendgrid, but when I receive the email, the email is in plain text format, and I would like to send it in html format.
The variable data is the data I pass to sgMail.send.

```
module.exports = {
data: {
    to: '',
    from: '',
    subject: '',
    text: '',
    templateId: '',
    dynamic_template_data: {
        value_precip: undefined,
        value_humidity: undefined,
        value_windSpeed: undefined,
        value_condition: undefined,
        value_activiti: undefined
    }
},

set: function(to, from, subject, text, templateId, params) {
    this.data.to = to
    this.data.from = from
    this.data.subject = subject
    this.data.text = text
    this.data.templateId = templateId,
    this.data.dynamic_template_data.value_precipitation = params.value_precipitation
    this.data.dynamic_template_data.value_humidity = params.value_humidity
    this.data.dynamic_template_data.value_windSpeed = params.value_windy
    this.data.dynamic_template_data.value_condition = params.value_condition
    this.data.dynamic_template_data.value_activiti = params.value_activiti

},
    send: function() {
    try {
        sgMail.send(this.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

   }
}
```

I don't know what may be causing this problem, if anyone can help me I would be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, just remove the `text`.

As mentioned by a contributor of SendGrid. [Read more](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/1044#issuecomment-592561059)

> Given that dynamic templates contain both HTML and plain text content, text should not be passed when using a dynamic template.

Comment: Can we mark that as the answer ? I've search the fix for that for weeks ! The data were working and everything, but couldn't find why my template was not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SendGrid uses `html` attribute to decide if the content type should be html even though they ignore the content. So, just include that attribute in the payload. Seems weird, but it worked for me.

P.S.: I didn't try it with JavaScript, I'm using Python.

Comment: "Try..." reads like a debugging experiment proposal, which is more of a clarification question than an answer. As such this should be a comment ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Please rephrase this into a conditional answer like "If the root cause of your problem is ... then the solution is to ..."